# Generate font collection book

Tags: fonts

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`fontbook`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontbook)

Is there a package to generate a font collection book/catalogue from all fonts in the system (`fc-list`) or by selecting a list of fonts?

Ideally, it would print a small example, and list the features of the font (specially, the OTF features such as ligatures, small caps, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I haven't found anything, I've begun making one myself. The layout is quite simple. It is based on XeTeX/fontspec and uses only two macros:

```
\newcommand{\sampletext}[2][]{%
 {\par\csname#2\endcsname \csname#1\endcsname
 #2 #1\\
 Dans l'affliction éphémère qui m'accable, je teste
 la police d'affichage qui est affichée sur cette page 1 2 3 4 5.
 }
}


\newcommand{\printfont}[3][\empty]{%
   \fontspec[#1]{#2}
   \section*{#2 #1 --- Licence: #3}
   \ifx#1\empty
     \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}
   \else
     \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
   \fi

   \sampletext{huge}
   \sampletext{LARGE}
   \sampletext{Large}
   \sampletext{large}
   \sampletext{normalsize}
   \sampletext{small}
   \sampletext{footnotesize}
   \sampletext{scriptsize}
   \sampletext{tiny}
   \sampletext[scshape]{large}
   \sampletext[itshape]{large}
   \sampletext[bfseries]{large}
   \pagebreak
}
```

The full project can be found [on github](https://github.com/raphink/fontbook). A new `fontbook` package is on its way to the CTAN.

Contributions are most welcome.

Comment: please provide an example how to use `\printfont`.

Comment: @Friendly Ghost: see fontbook.pdf in the github project, as well as fontbook-freefonts.tex for an example.

Comment: + 1 It is very useful reference. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if there's features you'd like to see in this package.

Comment: [That was quick](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/fontbook).

Comment: @Emre: it was, indeed :-)